# How to get Azure Function PowerShell on Apple M1 working?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

does someone of you has a working solutions for Azure Function PowerShell for an Apple M1?

I was not able to get it working. What I've tried so far:

Local approach:

- Installed .NET Core 3.1 SDK
- Installed Azure Function Tools 4
- Created Azure Function for PowerShell with a HTTP trigger function

When I run "func start" I'm getting the following error message:

```
An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.deps.json) was not found:
package: 'runtime.osx-x64.runtime.native.System.IO.Ports', version: '4.7.0'
```

Docker approach:

- Created Docker image from "mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/powershell:4-powershell7.2". I've tried it with and without buildx --platform linux/amd64
- Started the image (also with and without --platform linux/amd64)

Then I get the following error:

```
fail: Host.Startup[515]
      A host error has occurred during startup operation '6c64e86e-4fff-4784-a6b1-c86a60ac9c8e'.
      System.IO.IOException: Function not implemented
         at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEvents()
         at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEventsIfNotDisposed()
         at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.set_EnableRaisingEvents(Boolean value)
         at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.IO.AutoRecoveringFileSystemWatcher.InitializeWatcher() in /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/IO/AutoRecoveringFileSystemWatcher.cs:line 64
         at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.IO.AutoRecoveringFileSystemWatcher..ctor(String path, String filter, Boolean includeSubdirectories, WatcherChangeTypes changeTypes, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) in /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/IO/AutoRecoveringFileSystemWatcher.cs:line 43
         at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Eventing.File.FileWatcherEventSource..ctor(IScriptEventManager eventManager, String source, String path, String filter, Boolean includeSubdirectories, WatcherChangeTypes changeTypes, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) in /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Eventing/File/FileWatcherEventSource.cs:line 28
         at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.FileMonitoringService.InitializeFileWatchers() in /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/FileMonitoringService.cs:line 157
         at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.FileMonitoringService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/FileMonitoringService.cs:line 93
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebJobsScriptHostService.UnsynchronizedStartHostAsync(ScriptHostStartupOperation activeOperation, Int32 attemptCount, JobHostStartupMode startupMode) in /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/WebJobsScriptHostService.cs:line 310
```

Is there any way to get it working on an Apple M1?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Regards
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple M1 is not *officially* supported at this point, but this may work:

1. Make sure you have the latest Core Tools v4 installed (4.0.4590+).
2. In the `local.settings.json` file, set `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME_VERSION` to `"7.2"`. PowerShell 7.0 is not (and probably will not be) supported on Apple M1.